# Jquery asp.net Button Click Event via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, events

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.
I have an asp.net button with a click event (that runs some server side code).
What i'd like to  do is call this event via ajax and jquery.
Is there any way to do this? If so, i would love some examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is where jQuery really shines for ASP.Net developers.  Lets say you have this ASP button:

When that renders, you can look at the source of the page and the id on it won't be btnAwesome, but $ctr001_btnAwesome or something like that.  This makes it a pain in the butt to find in javascript.  Enter jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id$='btnAwesome']").click(function() {
    // Do client side button click stuff here.
  });
});
```

The id$= is doing a regex match for an id ENDING with btnAwesome.

Edit:

Did you want the ajax call being called from the button click event on the client side?  What did you want to call?  There are a lot of really good articles on using jQuery to make ajax calls to ASP.Net code behind methods.

The gist of it is you create a **static** method marked with the WebMethod attribute.  You then can make a call to it using jQuery by using $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

I learned my WebMethod stuff from: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

A lot of really good ASP.Net/jQuery stuff there.  Make sure you read up about why you have to use msg.d in the return on .Net 3.5 (maybe since 3.0) stuff.

Comment: +1, the ASP related answer is probably the one he is looking for. :)

Comment: Could be, but I want to believe no one uses classic ASP ;)

Comment: And I want to spread the good word about using the regex matching for ASP.Net controls!

Comment: Do you know how this would work if the button is on a master page?
Is there a way to determine the content page name such as ContentPage1.aspx?

Comment: If the javascript is loaded on every page that uses the master page, it should work fine.

Answer (score 15):

I like Gromer's answer, but it leaves me with a question: What if I have multiple 'btnAwesome's in different controls?

To cater for that possibility, I would do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=myButton.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    // Do client side button click stuff here.
  });
});
```

It's not a regex match, but in my opinion, a regex match isn't what's needed here. If you're referencing a particular button, you want a precise text match such as this.

If, however, you want to do the same action for every btnAwesome, then go with Gromer's answer.

Comment: why not use the id selector directly like I did in my answer:
$('#<%=myButton.ClientID %>')

Comment: Good point.  I've never run into that with buttons, but your point is very valid.

Comment: Marwan: No particular reason. It would seem your JQuery-fu is better than mine. Edited.

Answer (score 10):

ASP.NET web forms page already have a JavaScript method for handling PostBacks called "__doPostBack".

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Use the following in your code file to generate the JavaScript that performs the PostBack.  Using this method will ensure that the proper ClientID for the control is used.

```
protected string GetLoginPostBack()
{
    return Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnLogin, string.Empty);
}
```

Then in the ASPX page add a javascript block.

```
<script language="javascript">
function btnLogin_Click() {
  <%= GetLoginPostBack() %>;
}
</script>
```

The final javascript will be rendered like this.

```
<script language="javascript">
function btnLogin_Click() {
  __doPostBack('btnLogin','');
}
</script>
```

Now you can use "btnLogin_Click()" from your javascript to submit the button click to the server.

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason.
Here's what i have so far:
Code Behind
protected string GetLoginPostBack()
{return Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnLogin,string.Empty);
}
public void lnkbtnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ // do stuff }
My HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function btnLogin_Click() {
  <%= GetLoginPostBack() %>;
}
 $("#<%= btnLogin.ClientID %>").click(function() { 
           btnLogin_Click();
   });
});
</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" />

Answer (score 4):

In the client side handle the click event of the button, use the ClientID property to get he id of the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#<%=myButton.ClientID %>,#<%=muSecondButton.ClientID%>").click(

    function() {
     $.get("/myPage.aspx",{id:$(this).attr('id')},function(data) {
       // do something with the data
     return false;
     }
    });
 });
```

In your page on the server:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e) {
 // check if it is an ajax request
 if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") {
  if (Request.QueryString["id"]==myButton.ClientID) {
    // call the click event handler of the myButton here
    Response.End();
  }
  if (Request.QueryString["id"]==mySecondButton.ClientID) {
    // call the click event handler of the mySecondButton here
    Response.End();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
Is there a way to specify the event if i have more than one button?
i.e. btnSave, btnNew and then sever side code behind has
btnSave_Click, and btnNew_Click events.

Answer (score 3):

I found myself wanting to do this and I reviewed the above answers and did a hybrid approach of them.  It got a little tricky, but here is what I did:

My button already worked with a server side post. I wanted to let that to continue to work so I left the "OnClick" the same, but added a OnClientClick:

```
OnClientClick="if (!OnClick_Submit()) return false;"
```

Here is my full button element in case it matters:

```
<asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth jiveSiteSettingsSubmit" OnClientClick="if (!OnClick_Submit()) return false;" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" Text="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_okbutton_text%>" id="BtnOK" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,okbutton_accesskey%>" Enabled="true"/>
```

If I inspect the onclick attribute of the HTML button at runtime it actually looks like this:

```
if (!OnClick_Submit()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl03$RptControls$BtnOK", "", true, "", "", false, true))
```

Then in my Javascript I added the OnClick_Submit method.  In my case I needed to do a check to see if I needed to show a dialog to the user.  If I show the dialog I return false causing the event to stop processing.  If I don't show the dialog I return true causing the event to continue processing and my postback logic to run as it used to.

```
function OnClick_Submit() {
    var initiallyActive = initialState.socialized && initialState.activityEnabled;
    var socialized = IsSocialized();
    var enabled = ActivityStreamsEnabled();

    var displayDialog;

    // Omitted the setting of displayDialog for clarity

    if (displayDialog) {
        $("#myDialog").dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in my Javascript code that runs when the dialog is accepted, I do the following depending on how the user interacted with the dialog:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog('close');
__doPostBack('message', '');
```

The "message" above is actually different based on what message I want to send.

### But wait, there's more!

Back in my server-side code, I changed OnLoad from:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e)
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }

    // OnLoad logic removed for clarity
}
```

To:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e)
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        switch (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"])
        {
            case "message1":
                // We did a __doPostBack with the "message1" command provided
                Page.Validate();
                BtnSave_Click(this, new CommandEventArgs("message1", null));
                break;

            case "message2":
                // We did a __doPostBack with the "message2" command provided
                Page.Validate();
                BtnSave_Click(this, new CommandEventArgs("message2", null));
                break;
            }
            return;
    }

    // OnLoad logic removed for clarity
}
```

Then in BtnSave_Click method I do the following:

```
CommandEventArgs commandEventArgs = e as CommandEventArgs;
string message = (commandEventArgs == null) ? null : commandEventArgs.CommandName;
```

And finally I can provide logic based on whether or not I have a message and based on the value of that message.

Comment: Looking back I probably could have simplified this some if I changed my button from a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button to a System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton, but I'm sticking with it for now because it's working fine.